# SVG HTML link not displaying in IE but displays in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

I am displaying a graph with text and links below the graph.  All the code is in SVG.  Below is my **text** code and below that is my **html** code.  The **text** displays in all tested browsers (including IE)  The **hmtl** code displays fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

### TEXT:

```
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "spikes")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + "," + (totalHeight + labelMargin * 3) + ")")
        .style("font-size", "1.2em")
        .style("font-weight", "bold")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .text("Total SF Represented: " + squareFt);
```

### HTML LINK:

```
        var spikesLinkText = "Invalid Interval Usage Spikes Removed: " + numberOfSpikesTotal;
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("class", "spikes")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + graphWidth) + "," + (totalHeight + labelMargin * 2) + ")")
            .style("font-size", "1.2em")
            .style("font-weight", "bold")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .html("<a href='#'>" + spikesLinkText + "</a>")
            .on("click", function (d) {
                onClickNumberSpikes();
            });
```

### Screen Captures:

#### Report ran in Chrome or Firefox:

[image]

#### Report ran in IE:

[image]

Also, when I inspect the source in IE this links are not there.  But they are there in Chrome and Firefox.  What do I need to change to make the html code be included and display in IE?

#### The link opens a modal window:

```
onClickNumberSpikes = function () {
    $('#numberOfSpikesModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    initNumberOfSpikesTable(stateMap.hierarchyId);
}
```

Comment: I think Chrome and Firefox are more forgiving of your html method call mistake (they likely convert it to SVG). Why are you calling the html method instead of generating the link with append?

Comment: I added the method that is called to the end of my question.  It opens a modal window that displays a table of Electrical Spikes captured in the data.

Comment: Can you post a working snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up changing the link to text and adding a style in the .css file to make the text look like a link on hover.

### .SVG

```
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("class", "spikes plink")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + graphWidth) + "," + (totalHeight + labelMargin * 2) + ")")
            .style("font-size", "1.2em")
            .style("font-weight", "bold")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Invalid Interval Usage Spikes Removed: " + numberOfSpikesTotal)
            .on("click", function (d) {
                onClickNumberSpikes();
            });
```

### .CSS

```
.plink:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```